# SQL table caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, iis

I have a Webservice for searching in a Table that changes once a day.
I am using this code to make a select method on the SQL table:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
{
    string sql = @"SELECT TOP 60 * FROM movies WHERE title like @Search";

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Search", "%" + searchQuery + "%");

        con.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Read
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that if I cache the table to a memory object it will help to decrease the time for each selection.
Is there any way to make a select method on a cache object and not on a SQL table?

## Edit

Maybe something like saving the SQL table to a local memory

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many records do you have / how long does it take to run that query ?

Comment: i have 17000 records, but it's search engine that will be run every second

Comment: It's run every second ? It it a website and many users are querying lists or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will save the data to local memory and you can search it

```
HashSet<string> Titles = new HashSet<string>() { "Gone With The Wind", "Terminator", "Windtalkeer" };
String search = "Wind";
IEnumerable<string> MatchingTitles = Titles.Where(x => (x.Contains(search)));
foreach (string title in MatchingTitles) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(title);
```

That LINQ search will be O(n)
It will not use any index

But even in SQL a like '% does not use an index

Is a case of premature optimization?
Do you know that SQL is a performance bottle neck?

Is SQL on the same server?
SQL will also cache recent data in memory.
A search against 17,000 records every second should not be a problem.
How long does the existing query take?

A cache that is O(1) would be

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

Where the key is the search and value is the list of titles.
First check if the search has already been run.
Once the dictionary get over X in size then just clear it out and start fresh.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is pretty good at searching data. Caching your information locally will only perform better if the amount or records you search is relatively small (the overhead of actually calling SQL Server will be the slowing factor in that case).

Otherwise, since your query uses wildcards, indexing your column will not help accelerate the query. You could take a look at [Full-Text Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).